# How to get list of directories from Artifactory repo using groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have the below groovy script in one of my Jenkins Active choice parameters:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
versions = getArtifactsVersions()
def getArtifactsVersions(){
   def responseJson = "curl -k -X GET https://{Artifatory_URL}/storage/my-repo/".execute().text
   def projectList = (new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(responseJson)).children
   return projectList
}
```

Its supposes to return list of Folders which exists in this path (without subdirctories), however, the result I gets from it is:

```
{uri=/TEST_FOR_YONI, folder=true}
{uri=/TEST_FOR_PKMLODEL_V2, folder=true}
```

how can I change it to return:

```
TEST_FOR_YONI
TEST_FOR_PKMLODEL_V2
```

For debug, I ran the below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def responseJson = "curl -k -X GET https://{Artifatory_URL}/storage/my-repo/".execute().text
print responseJson
```

and it reruns the below:

```
{
  "repo" : "my-repo",
  "path" : "/",
  "created" : "2020-11-29T18:00:42.635+02:00",
  "lastModified" : "2020-11-29T18:00:42.635+02:00",
  "lastUpdated" : "2020-11-29T18:00:42.635+02:00",
  "children" : [ {
    "uri" : "/TEST_FOR_YONI",
    "folder" : true
  }, {
    "uri" : "/TEST_FOR_PKLMODEL_V2",
    "folder" : true
  }
  ],
  "uri" : "https://{Artifatory_URL}/storage/my-repo/"
}
```

Comment: please show what you have before JsonSlurper in `responseJson` variable

Comment: According to the code, `projectList` should be a Map, but instead looks like a JSON String in the example output. Is that correct?

Comment: ok. what `https://{Artifatory_URL}/storage/my-repo/` returns ?

Comment: @daggett I added now that info in the question, and thanks for your suggestion, I was able to see what is the issue. I had to add `.uri` after `children`. Now I just have to get rid from the backslash at the beginning. any idea for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def responseJson='''
{
  "repo" : "my-repo",
  "path" : "/",
  "created" : "2020-11-29T18:00:42.635+02:00",
  "lastModified" : "2020-11-29T18:00:42.635+02:00",
  "lastUpdated" : "2020-11-29T18:00:42.635+02:00",
  "children" : [ {
    "uri" : "/TEST_FOR_YONI",
    "folder" : true
  }, {
    "uri" : "/TEST_FOR_PKLMODEL_V2",
    "folder" : true
  }
  ],
  "uri" : "https://{Artifatory_URL}/storage/my-repo/"
}
'''


def projectList = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(responseJson).children.collect{ it.uri.substring(1) }
```